# best way to connect Apache superset with openSearch (AWS managed elasticSearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-visualization, apache-superset

I'm looking to connect opensearch with apache superset but I dont see much documentation.
Do we have to use AWS managed superset also in order to connect to opensearch( AWS managed elaticsearch) ?

Answer (score 2):

Supersets support to connect query engines, You can choose any query engines which supports OpenSearch